# Trouble updating an outer array from inside a mongoose query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an array that I'd like to fill with objects, but the console prints out []. I know this is a problem with the async nature of mongoose, but I'm not sure how to fix it... I want itemCart to be filled with all the user's items.

Any guidance/help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Here is the code:

```
let itemCart = [];
  User
  .findById(req.params.username)
  .then(user => {
    for (let i = 0; i < user.cart.length; i++) {
      let itemId = user.cart[i];
      Item.findById(itemId).then(item => {
        itemCart.push(item);
      });
    }
    console.log(itemCart); // returns []

  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err)
  });
```

Comment: Can you please add User and Item model codes to the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply async/await like this:-

```
let itemCart = [];
User
.findById(req.params.username)
.then(async user => {
 for (let i = 0; i < user.cart.length; i++) {
  let itemId = user.cart[i];
  Let item = await Item.findById(itemId);
   itemCart.push(item);

  }
  console.log(itemCart); // now it will return the array

  })
  .catch(err => {
   console.error(err)
   });
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Thanks so much!